# How can I submit a contract on PolygonScan when it has found a similar contract?

Tags: polygon

[image]

I was trying to verify my contract, but it automatically found itself a similar contract (which was the one I submitted some days ago when I test another contract). Now there's no option for me to submit a contract file for this contract, and the functions in "Write Contract" tab are all not usable. Is there a way to let me submit a contract file for it in this stage?

It is on Mumbai PolygonScan btw.